# The global sections of tensor powers of an invertible sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme. Let $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. My question is that whether the canonical map 
$$
\Gamma(X,\mathcal{L})\otimes_{\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)}\Gamma(X,\mathcal{L}) \to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{L})
$$
is always surjective. Actually, I want to known whether the graded ring 
$$\Gamma_*(X,\mathcal{L})= \bigoplus\nolimits_{n\geq0} \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})$$ is always generated by homogeneous element of degree one.

Any comment is welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No. For example, if $X$ is an elliptic curve (smooth projective over say complex numbers), it has 2-torsion line bundles. For such an $L$, the left hand side is zero, but the right hand side is not in the above map.

Comment: Hi, Mohan, Thanks.

Comment: @G.-S.Zhou, it would be useful that you write an answer based on Mohan's comment above.

Comment: Is there a class of situations where this is true? For example, if $X$ is noetherian and $\mathcal{L}$ is generated by finitely many global sections?

Comment: @Mohan why is the left side zero?

Comment: @DavidLui  If $L$ is a non- trivial torsion line bundle, it has no non- zero sections.