# If $L$ is very ample, is the graded ring $\oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n})$ finitely generated in degree 1 over degree 0?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme (If necessary assume $X$ is separated and finite type) over a ring $R$. Let $L$ be a very ample invertible sheaf on $X$, as defined in definition [29.38.1 in the Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VM). Is the graded ring $\oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n})$ finitely generated in degree 1 over degree 0?

I tried some examples : if $X = \mathbb{P}^n_R$ and $L = O(1)$, then $\Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n})$ is just a polynomial ring. By theorem [29.39.1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02NP), there is an immersion $i : X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_R$ with $L = i^* O(1)$. I tried to use that to reduce the general case to the $X = \mathbb{P}^n_R$ case. But since $i$ is just an immersion, I can't figure out how to relate $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n_R, O(n))$ with $\Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n})$ .

I did some searching and found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368916/the-global-sections-of-tensor-powers-of-an-invertible-sheaf) but the counterexample involves a non-torsion invertible sheaf on an elliptic curve, so it can't be very ample.

Comment: If this is false, is this is weaker statement true: if  $L$ is ample, is there a $d$ such that $\oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes dn})$ is finitely generated in degree 1 over degree 0

Comment: My guess is that the strong statement is false, but I’m not sure. I think a start could be the keyword “projectively normal embeddings”, but I’m not sure about the exact relationship to your question.